# Training recurrent neural network when using GPU acceleration by TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have a basic knowledge of parallel computing (including some CUDA), feedforward neural networks, and recurrent neural networks (and how they use BPTT).

When using for example TensorFlow you can apply GPU acceleration for the training phase of a network. But recurrent neural networks are sequential in nature, having timesteps where a current timestep depends on a previous, and the next timestep depends on the current, etc.

How come GPU acceleration works if it is like this? Is everything that can be computed in parallel computed in that way, while the timestep dependent parts are serialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RNNs train using backpropagation through time. The recurrent network structure is unfolded into a directed acyclic graph of finite length and looks just as a normal feedforward net would. It then trains using stochastic gradient descent where in between each time step there is a constraint that the weights must be equal.

If you understand that it trains like this, as in it is just constrained backpropagation on sequences of a given length, you see there is nothing about the sequential nature that is stopping this process from being parallelizable.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. I didn't write it in the first question, but as I have understood BPTT from reading about it (and RNN) it does exactly what you say. So if I would just "fold out", or place the same network next to each other for several timesteps, and imagine edges between the unfolded networks (representing the recurrent connections), it is really just like regular backpropagation?

Comment: yes it is just backprop but constrained for weights to be the same between layers. it is for this reason you have to be weary of exploding or vanishing gradients when trying to model long term dependencies. note you also have some flexibility in how you define your unfolding process, not just in terms of length but also structure. so network structure may not look regular as in feedforward.

Comment: I have trouble understand the point "training RNN is inherently expensive because it cannot be parallelized" as well. As for this understanding of unfolding RNN, I see no reason why it should be any more expensive than a feedforward networks. Perhaps only the longer the sequence in RNN, the deeper the layers in feedforward.

Answer (score 3):

The way you can get performance for GPU training of recurrent neural networks is by using a large enough batch size that computing the forward/backward pass for a single cell consumes enough compute to make the GPU busy.